# How to create an index on an XML column in PostgreSQL with an xpath expression?

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath, indexing, amazon-aurora

I'm running into this error when attempting to create a btree index on an XML data type column that uses an xpath expression on AuroraDB - PostgreSQL 9.6:

```
ERROR:  could not identify a comparison function for type xml
SQL state: 42883
```

This 2009 thread without a clear resolution is the only one I've found discussing this error message in regards to creating an xpath based index for a much earlier version of PostgreSQL: 
https://www.postgresql-archive.org/Slow-select-times-on-select-with-xpath-td2074839.html

In my case I do also need to specify namespaces as well and the original poster in that thread cast the result of the xpath expression to text[] which does get by the error for me too - but why is that even needed?  I also don't see PostgreSQL ever using my index even when I have thousands of rows to go through.

So I tried out a simpler case and the error still occurs - please shed some light as to why if you could:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    xml_data xml NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT test_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;



CREATE INDEX test_idx
    ON test USING btree 
    (xpath('/book/title', xml_data))
```

and the resulting message is:

```
ERROR:  could not identify a comparison function for type xml
SQL state: 42883
```

The database encoding is UTF8.
The Collation and Character Type are en_US.UTF-8.

Some sample insert statements too:

```
insert into source_data.test(id, xml_data) 
values(1, XMLPARSE (DOCUMENT '<?xml version="1.0"?><book><title>Manual</title><chapter>1</chapter><chapter>2</chapter></book>'))

insert into source_data.test(id, xml_data) 
values(2, XMLPARSE (DOCUMENT '<?xml version="1.0"?><book><title>Apropos</title><chapter>1</chapter><chapter>2</chapter></book>'))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your getting this error because the [XML data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-xml.html) does not provide any [comparison operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-xml.html#id-1.5.7.21.7), hence you can't create an index on the result of `xpath()`, because it returns [an array of XML values](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PROCESSING).

Therefore you need to cast the XPath expression to a text array when creating the index:

```
CREATE INDEX test_idx
ON test USING BTREE 
    (cast(xpath('/book/title', xml_data) as text[])) ;
```

This index then gets used when querying the table:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT * FROM test where
cast(xpath('/book/title', xml_data) as text[]) = '{<title>Apropos</title>}';
```

gives

```
                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Index Scan using test_idx on test  (cost=0.13..8.15 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.034..0.038 rows=1 loops=1)
    Index Cond: ((xpath('/book/title'::text, xml_data, '{}'::text[]))::text[] = '{<title>Apropos</title>}'::text[])
Planning time: 0.168 ms
Execution time: 0.073 ms (4 rows)
```

This works the same when using `text()`:

```
CREATE INDEX test_idx
ON test USING BTREE 
    (cast(xpath('/book/title/text()', xml_data) as text[])) ;

explain analyze select * from test where
cast(xpath('/book/title/text()', xml_data) as text[]) = '{Apropos}';
```

gives

```
                                                   QUERY PLAN                                                   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using test_idx on test  (cost=0.13..8.15 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.034..0.038 rows=1 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((xpath('/book/title/text()'::text, xml_data, '{}'::text[]))::text[] = '{Apropos}'::text[])
 Planning time: 0.166 ms
 Execution time: 0.076 ms
(4 rows)
```

Note that I forced the use of the index via the following command, as I only had 4 rows in the test table I created.

```
SET enable_seqscan TO off;
```

Comment: It would be nice as well to be able to create an index on text()  like say (cast(xpath('/book/title/text()', xml_data) as text));  but that'll result in ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE    Does that mean text() is considered mutable and there's no way around that?

Comment: @Khorkrak I added an example using `text()`.